# jquery changing document flow

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to rearrange the document flow based on screen width. In my example I am trying to relocate two divs back and forth based on the screen width.

The first is a menu div which I want to move up in the document when the screen width is 480px to just after the header div, and then move back to its default position whenever the screen width is above 480px. This part of the code is working perfectly.

The other div though, the searchbox isn't. In my example, when the screen width is below 480px, I want to move the form element from another div element called #headerRight and move it inside the #footer element, but before any other element preexisting in the #footer.

I am doing this by the .prepend() command in jquery. And then when the screen width is above 480px.
I want to move it back to its original position in the #headerRight div.

So, the form element works as it should when the width is below 480, it moves into the #footer div before any content in that div. But when I resize the screen width to above 480px, it does not return back to its original position in the #headerRight div.
This is my jsfiddle [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/lupis/818fy8b9/7/).

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(ChangeDiv);
    $(window).trigger("resize");   
});

function ChangeDiv() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
        $("#menu").after($("#header"));
        $("#headerRight form").prependTo($("#footer"));
    } else {
        $("#header").after($("#menu"));
        $("#footer").prependTo($("headerRight form"));
    }
}
```

Thanks
-Sohail

Comment: Looks like it's working the way you describe on the fiddle that you've posted.

Comment: Actually its not, as the search box stays in the footer when resized to be larger then 480px. The menu reverts back to its original position when larger then 480px but the serachbox doesn't.

Comment: You’re missing a `#` before `headerRight` …

Comment: @CBroe yes you are correct, but by doing that the footer is placed in the header, and then when resized under 480px, the footer and the searchbox are gone and remain so when resied back to above 480px

Comment: almost getting there, I used the following code now:

$(function () {
    $(window).resize(ChangeDiv);
    $(window).trigger("resize");   
});

function ChangeDiv() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
        $("#menu").after($("#header"));
        $("#headerRight form").prependTo($("#footer"));
    } else {
        $("#header").after($("#menu"));
        $("#footer form").prependTo($("#headerRight"));
    }
}

So the searchbox is in the footer when under 480px, and is getting back into the header now, but before the phonenr and not after as the default was

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :) This is the code I used:

```
$(function () {
    $(window).resize(ChangeDiv);
    $(window).trigger("resize");   
});

function ChangeDiv() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width <= 480) {
        $("#menu").after($("#header"));
        $("#headerRight form").prependTo($("#footer"));
    } else {
        $("#header").after($("#menu"));
        $("#footer form").appendTo($("#headerRight"));
    }
}
```

So both the menu and seachbox divs change their positions when under 480px and revert back to their original positions when resized back to above 480px